# How to make a table like this with fpdf using PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf, tabular

How do you make a table like this with FPDF using PHP?

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with $this->Cell.

[image]

Comment: I don't think people here are going to code for you. fpdf has a very nice documentation and you should try and then if you face problem you can ask here

Comment: You can look this page http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm (or www.google.com and search 'table in fpdf')

Comment: i do not want fill code. just basic idea or little sample. i tried but formating problem. @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: You can't do this with method Cell() because you can only give text. Doc : http://www.fpdf.org/fr/doc/cell.htm

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Comment: thanks everyone for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK .. let's try. Just an example .. an idea. ok ?

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.3);

// Title row
$pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
$pdf->Cell(100, 8, "LEARNING POTENTIAL", 1, 0, 'L', true);
$pdf->SetFont('', '');
$pdf->Cell(20, 8, "Score", 1, 0, 'C', true);
$pdf->Cell(20, 8, "Results", 1, 0, 'C', true);
$pdf->>Ln();

// Data rows

// (loop) foreach($data as $row) {

    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
    $pdf->Cell(100, 8, "Reasoning", "LTR", 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "", "LTR");
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "", "LTR");
    $pdf->>Ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
    $pdf->Cell(100, 8, "The ability to interpret information and", "LR", 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetFont('', '');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "6", "LR");
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "Effective", "LR");
    $pdf->>Ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
    $pdf->Cell(100, 8, "drawing accurate conclusions", "LBR", 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "", "LBR");
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "", "LBR");
    $pdf->>Ln();

// (end loop)
```

I divided each data row in 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks, @Jerry. It's more than an idea.